# get newsletter subscriber email in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.0, newsletter

I need to collect SubScriber email in Magento 2. So, I tried to inject `\Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber $subscriber` , I didn't work for me.

```
  <?php
    namespace Vendor\Module\Cron;

    class NewsLetter
    {
        protected $_logger;
        protected $_subscriber;
        protected $_customerdata;
        public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
           \Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber $subscriber,
           \Magento\Customer\CustomerData\Customer $customerdata,
           )
        {
        $this->_logger = $logger;
         $this->_subscriber= $subscriber;
        $this->_customerdata= $customerdata;
        }
        public function execute()
        {
           $customer= $this->_customerdata->getSectionData();
          $data=$this->getCustomerEmail($customer)
          foreach($data as $email)
         {
         $customerEmail =$email;

         $checkSubscriber = $this->_subscriber->loadByEmail($customerEmail);
        if ($checkSubscriber->isSubscribed()) {
            // Customer is subscribed
         $this->_logger->addDebug($customerEmail."subscribed Email");
        } else {
           $this->_logger->addDebug($customerEmail."Unsubscribed Email");
        }
         }

        }
    }
```

Suggest me what I missed.

Comment: for($data as $email) or foreach(......)    check

Comment: @BilalUsean  update question

Comment: How about your current issue?

Answer (score 2):

In your case, we can use `\Magento\Newsletter\Model\ResourceModel\Subscriber\CollectionFactory`.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Cron;

class NewsLetter
{


 /**
 * @var \Magento\Newsletter\Model\ResourceModel\Subscriber\CollectionFactory
 */
protected $_subcriberCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
         ......
        \Magento\Newsletter\Model\ResourceModel\Subscriber\CollectionFactory $subcriberCollectionFactory,
         ......
    )
    {
        ......
        $this->_subcriberCollectionFactory = $subcriberCollectionFactory;
    }
}
```

Load only subscribed customers:

```
$this->_subcriberCollectionFactory->create()->useOnlyCustomers();
```

Adds customer info to select:

```
$this->_subcriberCollectionFactory->create()->showCustomerInfo();
```

**See more: `vendor/magento/module-newsletter/Model/ResourceModel/Subscriber/Collection.php`**